# Having trouble updating nested field inside a document (Node.js/Mongo)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongojs

I only have one document in my collection:

```
{
     "_id":ObjectID("...."),

     "Last, First" : {
          "Mon 8/28":"10:15-9:00p",
          "Wed 8/31":"9:00a-12:00p"
      },
     ...
}
```

and I receive these variable from a AJAX call on the frontend

```
var name = "Last, First";
var date = "Wed 8/31";
var newTime = "10:00p-3:00a";
```

I am trying to make a call using MongoJS within Express.js to update the document with the new time but I am having trouble (new to the stack).  I tried using:

```
collection.update({}, {$set: {name.date : newTime}});
```

but I am having trouble updating it properly.  I would like to make it so that the nested document is updated with the new time coming in from the call. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to build the keys in JavaScript as anything "left side" or "key side" is always literally interpreted as a string. But there is a simple syntax to follow:

```
var name = "Last, First";
var date = "Wed 8/31";
var newTime = "10:00p-3:00a";

var update = { "$set": {} };

update.$set[name + "." + date] = newTime;

collection.update({}, update);
```

So the variable `update` is now constructed with a composite string using "dot notation" from each variable part. The bracket `[]` notation allows the construction of a key name when referencing an object, but of course the higher level `$set` key must first be set to something, otherwise this would be an error on assignment.